# Unusual installation of `aws` cli

Tags: macos, unix, aws-cli

I am using "MacOS High Sierra".

I installed the aws cli tool a long time ago, don't remember how I installed it.

The installation is a little unusual.

I can run `aws` from any folder, this is working

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.11.121 Python/2.7.13 Darwin/17.4.0 botocore/1.7.12
```

However running

```
$ which aws
```

this returns nothing.
I thought it might be an alias, but running

```
$ alias | grep aws
```

This also returns nothing.
Its not installed with homebrew either

```
$ brew list | grep aws
```

The reason why this is a problem, because there have now been a few cli programs I have ran (Including "AWS Sam" and a build script from my work) which are complaining because `aws` is not in the path.

I would much rather have a "regular installation" of the `aws` cli, where I put the executable in some `bin` folder and then put it in the environment path.

But instead its using some "magic" which I am unfamiliar with. And not even AWS owns tools ("AWS Sam") seem to like the way its installed.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `aws` was installed with `pip`, to the path `~/Library/Python/2.7/bin/`. But that is also in $PATH variable. Still has not solved my issue that `which aws` is returning nothing and other cli tools seem to think `aws` is not in path

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved the problem by running

```
$ pip uninstall awscli
$ brew upgrade
$ brew install awscli
```

Now I get this result

```
$ which aws
/usr/local/bin/aws
```

"AWS Sam" and the other build script I use at work are now working.